# Suggested pattern for view controller frame setting?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, design-patterns

I've run into the following sequence of actions many times in iOS dev, and never quite known what the suggested pattern is for implementation:

1) A view controller *A* creates a new view controller *B*

2) *A* sets the frame of *B*'s view

3) *B* then creates its own subviews, which need to be sized relative to its own view's frame

Note that this assumes *B* can't figure out its own frame, it needs to be set from a higher order VC.

---

So, given the following code:

```
b = CustomViewController()
b.frame = CGRectMake(...)
```

one will find that if they try to reference `self.frame` inside of *B*'s `viewDidLoad`, the frame is not yet available. So that approach fails. It is possible to add a new method to *B* like `createViews` or something, or even leverage `layoutSubviews`, but both of those are clumsy or potentially incorrect choices.

---

Another approach I've tried is making a custom initializer equivalent to `initWithFrame`, and then putting the new view creation right in the init, and while that works, it seems counter to Apple's basic setup for Cocoa, wherein UIViews have initWithFrame, and UIViewControllers simply have init or initWithNibName.

What is the recommend pattern, here?

Comment: Recommended pattern is to use autolayout.

Comment: That doesn't at all address the situation...

Comment: Yes it does.  You're concerned about who should be setting each others frames (which, with autolayout, should be *no one*), and more importantly, you're concerned with how to handle B's subviews.  If B's subviews are using auto layout, then it doesn't matter who, how, or when B's view's frame is set (which again, should be handled by autolayout constraints you add) because the autolayout constraints of B's subviews will always adjust themselves to correctly fit B.

Comment: And the autolayout relationship between A and B should be set at where ever the spot that B is added to A.  Your step 2 should be "A sets the autolayout constraints of B" (which means A defines constraints between the upper most view of B and whatever view of A it has added B to).  Your step 3 should be "B has nothing more to do because its autolayout constraints are already set up in interface builder or where ever I'm added its subviews to itself programmatically".